# Get caption of child window button on windows using uiautomation with c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

**I want to get this Zoom Meeting's "Mute My Audio" caption on windows using uiautomation with C++**

[image]

this is my calling current code:

```
// Get the handle of the Zoom Meetings window.
  zoomWnd = ::FindWindow(NULL, "Zoom Meeting");
  if (zoomWnd != NULL)
  {
    std::cout<<"zoom meeting"<<"\n";
    IUIAutomationElement *zoom = GetTopLevelWindowByName(L"Zoom Meeting");
    rawListDescendants(zoom, "Meeting");
  }
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
zoom meeting
sName: ContentLeftPanel
sName: VideoContainerWnd
sName: Video Content
sName:
sName:
sName:
```

**GetTopLevelWindowByName** Function definitions:

```
IUIAutomationElement *GetTopLevelWindowByName(LPWSTR windowName)
{
  if (windowName == NULL)
  {
    return NULL;
  }

  VARIANT varProp;
  varProp.vt = VT_BSTR;
  varProp.bstrVal = SysAllocString(windowName);
  if (varProp.bstrVal == NULL)
  {
    return NULL;
  }

  IUIAutomationElement *pRoot = NULL;
  IUIAutomationElement *pFound = NULL;

  // Get the desktop element.
  HRESULT hr = g_pAutomation->GetRootElement(&pRoot);
  if (FAILED(hr) || pRoot == NULL)
  {
    goto cleanup;
  }

  // Get a top-level element by name, such as "Program Manager"
  IUIAutomationCondition *pCondition = NULL;
  hr = g_pAutomation->CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, varProp, &pCondition);
  if (FAILED(hr))
  {
    goto cleanup;
  }

  pRoot->FindFirst(TreeScope_Children, pCondition, &pFound);

cleanup:
  if (pRoot != NULL)
    pRoot->Release();

  if (pCondition != NULL)
    pCondition->Release();

  VariantClear(&varProp);
  return pFound;
}
```

**rawListDescendants** Function definitions:

```
void rawListDescendants(IUIAutomationElement *pParent, std::string windowType)
{
  if (pParent == NULL)
    return;

  IUIAutomationTreeWalker *pControlWalker = NULL;
  IUIAutomationElement *pNode = NULL;

  g_pAutomation->get_RawViewWalker(&pControlWalker);
  if (pControlWalker == NULL)
  {
    goto cleanup;
  }

  pControlWalker->GetFirstChildElement(pParent, &pNode);
  if (pNode == NULL)
  {
    goto cleanup;
  }

  while (pNode)
  {
    BSTR desc;
    BSTR sName;

    pNode->get_CurrentLocalizedControlType(&desc);
    pNode->get_CurrentName(&sName);

    
    std::wcout<<"sName: "<<sName<<"\n";
    //std::wcout<<"desc: "<<desc<<"\n";

    // only go into windows and panes
    if (desc != NULL)
      if (0 == wcscmp(desc, L"window") || 0 == wcscmp(desc, L"pane"))
        rawListDescendants(pNode, windowType);

    if (desc != NULL)
      SysFreeString(desc);
    if (sName != NULL)
      SysFreeString(sName);

    // get the next element
    IUIAutomationElement *pNext;
    pControlWalker->GetNextSiblingElement(pNode, &pNext);
    pNode->Release();
    pNode = pNext;
  }

cleanup:
  if (pControlWalker != NULL)
    pControlWalker->Release();

  if (pNode != NULL)
    pNode->Release();

  return;
}
```

**Spy++ windows tree of Zoom Meeting window:**
[image]

**How can I crawl to child window and get it's button caption**

I have no prior experience with this library so please elaborate as much you can (Thanks)

---

Comment: Since you already discovered the documentation sections with source code ([How to Find UI Elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-howto-find-ui-elements) and [How to Walk the UI Automation Tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-howto-walk-uiautomation-tree)) you'll need to navigate the treeview on the left-hand side up to learn what the code you copied does, why, and how to incorporate the changes so that it does what you need.

Comment: @llnspectable thanks man... But can you help me with that, already spent 2 days on this problem..

Comment: Start by using the right tool. Spy++ isn't going to help. [Inspect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects) will.

Comment: @llnspectable thanks for that tool now I can see all the windows and element in it...  
https://imgur.com/a/tBXYqLM

Comment: @llnspectable I have made a function to list all descendent with recusrsive functionality...
But it is not list all windows. Here is code: https://www.codepile.net/pile/xPJQXpeZ    Here is all windows: https://imgur.com/a/tBXYqLM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here the code which worked...

```
IUIAutomationElement *zoom = GetTopLevelWindowByName(L"Zoom Meeting");
ListDescendants(zoom, 2);

void ListDescendants(IUIAutomationElement* pParent, int indent)
{
  osFocusZoomWindow();
  if (pParent == NULL)
      return;

  IUIAutomationTreeWalker* pControlWalker = NULL;
  IUIAutomationElement* pNode = NULL;

  g_pAutomation->get_ControlViewWalker(&pControlWalker);
  if (pControlWalker == NULL)
      goto cleanup;

  pControlWalker->GetFirstChildElement(pParent, &pNode);
  if (pNode == NULL)
      goto cleanup;

  while (pNode)
  {
      BSTR sName;
      pNode->get_CurrentName(&sName);
      //std::wcout << sName << L"\n";
      std::wstring strName(sName, SysStringLen(sName));
      if (strName.find(L"currently unmuted") != std::string::npos)
      {
        std::cout<<"####### UNMUTE"<<"\n";
      }else if(strName.find(L"currently muted") != std::string::npos){
        std::cout<<"####### MUTE"<<"\n";
      }
      SysFreeString(sName);

      ListDescendants(pNode, indent+1);
      IUIAutomationElement* pNext;
      pControlWalker->GetNextSiblingElement(pNode, &pNext);
      pNode->Release();
      pNode = pNext;
  }

cleanup:
  if (pControlWalker != NULL)
      pControlWalker->Release();

  if (pNode != NULL)
      pNode->Release();

  return;
}
```

Particularly in my case zoom has this feature that it shows all control button when we mouseover on zoom window. That's the reason I was not getting each window and button listed. So I just focused and set cursor position to zoom window before calling above function `osFocusZoomWindow()`

Comment: Thank you, I was having a hard time figuring out why the mute/unmute button was nowhere to be found. I almost gave up when I came across your post. Thumbs up!

Answer (score 0):

One solution is you can find all buttons using [`IUIAutomationElement::FindAll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nf-uiautomationclient-iuiautomationelement-findall), then compare the name with "*Mute My Audio*".

The following is an example you can refer to (I assume you alreay have the parent window handle of the button: `hwnd`):

```
IUIAutomation *pClientUIA;
IUIAutomationElement *pRootElement;

hr = pClientUIA->ElementFromHandle(hwnd, &pRootElement);
WCHAR controlName[] = L"Mute My Audio";
FindControl(UIA_ButtonControlTypeId, controlName);
```

FindControl function:

```
void FindControl(const long controlType, BSTR controlName)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    BSTR name;
    IUIAutomationCondition *pCondition;
    VARIANT varProp;
    varProp.vt = VT_I4;
    varProp.uintVal = controlType;
    hr = pClientUIA->CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_ControlTypePropertyId, varProp, &pCondition);

    IUIAutomationElementArray *pElementFound;
    hr = pRootElement->FindAll(TreeScope_Subtree, pCondition, &pElementFound);

    int eleCount;
    pElementFound->get_Length(&eleCount);
    if (eleCount == 0)
        return;

    for (int i = 0; i <= eleCount; i++)
    {
        IUIAutomationElement *pElement;
        hr = pElementFound->GetElement(i, &pElement);
        hr = pElement->get_CurrentName(&name);
        wprintf(L"Control Name: %s\n", name);

        if (!lstrcmp(controlName, name))
        {
            printf("Found it!\n");    
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Han Thanks for response Hey I made these two variable 
IUIAutomation *pClientUIA; 
IUIAutomationElement *pRootElement;  
global so FindControl can use it.   But there is some strange behavior code return pClientUIA  and next line after it doen't execute...

Comment: tried std::cout<<"done"; but it never reach there

Comment: Rita Han - MSFT  I have made a function to list all descendent with recusrsive functionality... But it is not list all windows. Here is code: codepile.net/pile/xPJQXpeZ Here is all windows: imgur.com/a/tBXYqLM